# Как подключить python-скрипт к html в Django

Tags: html, python, ajax, django

Работаю с Django. Имеется главная страница написанная на html, на ней располагается кнопка. По нажатию на кнопку, с помощью ajax-запроса, нужно получить python-script и каким-то образом его запустить.

Вот, к примеру, маленький скрипт:

```
import random 
print(random.randint(0,1000000))
```

Answer (score 1):

В файле *urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import MyAction

urlpatterns = [
    path('myaction/', MyAction.as_view(), name='my-action'),
]
```

В файле *views.py* создаём наш класс `MyAction`. Пишем в нём функцию `post`, которая будет принимать только POST запросы.

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import JsonResponse
import random 


class MyAction(View):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
            data = {}

            # Получаем данные из запроса
            action = self.request.POST.get('action')

            # Проверяем что значение соответствует ожидаемому
            # и возвращаем число
            # иначе строку с текстом Error
            if action == 'NeedRandom':
                data['result'] = random.randint(0,1000000)
            else:
                data['result'] = 'Error'
            return JsonResponse(data)
```

Создаём наш JavaScript, который будет отсылает запрос на сервер по указанному URL при нажатии на кнопку имеющую атрибут `class="mybutton"` и получать от него ответ в `success: function(data){...}`, ответ будет виден в консоли браузера.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Forming csrf_token
    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                let cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    };


    let data = {}

    $('.mybutton').on('click', function(e){
        data['action'] = 'NeedRandom';
        data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = getCookie('csrftoken');
        SendAjax();
    });


    function SendAjax(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/myaction/',
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cached: true,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

И, соответственно, сама кнопка на странице.

```
<input type="submit" class="mybutton" value="Случайное число">
```

Не забудьте подключить на странице JQuery библиотеку и JS-файл с Ajax скриптом