# Как вызвать python(django) скрипт при нажатии кнопки на html странице?

Tags: html, python, django

Есть функция создания рандомного числа на python(django)

```
def generate_code():
    random.seed()
    return str(random.randint(10000,99999))
```

Как выполнить этот код на html странице при нажатии кнопки?

Comment: Если речь идет про django (он указан в тэгах), то c помощью js дернуть нужный view и обработать ответ тоже с помощью js.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров да , про django
я имел ввиду django
где-то тут на форуме видел похожую тему, но потерял и не могу найти.
там вроде с помощью ajax ,обращались к серверу и получали рандомное число
просто я только начал изучать django
c js еще не очень силен
может есть ссылка где почитать как это делать? на похожем примере

Comment: @user355827, https://metanit.com/python/django/

Comment: @user355827 ну по ajax написано так много, что вы легко нагуглите как сделать запрос. А view в django мало чем отличается от любого другого view. Если это рандомное число никак не исползуется в вашем бэкенде, а просто нужно на самой веб-странице - то вам не стоит так делать. Просто сгенерируйте рандомное число на JS, как вам написали в ответах. Это гораздо проще.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873368/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-python-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%ba-html-%d0%b2-django/873458#873458
нашел такую тему, сделал все точно также, в итоге страница не открывается.
Пишет страница не доступна куда вывожу кнопку. Не подскажите в чем дело

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас в вопросе стоит метка `django`, рискну предположить, что вам не принципиально и предложу вместо него использовать `flask`

## [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com)

- ru - [основы фласк](https://pythonru.com/uroki/3-osnovy-flask)
- eng - [quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods)

### что необходимо:

- python3
- pip
- venv `python3 -m pip install virtualenv`

### подготовка

- `python3 -m pip install virtualenv`
- `python3 -m virtualenv .env`
- `source .env/bin/activate`
- `python3 -m pip install flask`

### запуск

- `python3 -m virtualenv .env`
- `python main.py`

### код

```py
# main.py
import random
from flask import Flask, request


def generate_code():
    random.seed()
    return str(random.randint(10000,99999))

app = Flask(__name__)

nav = '''
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/rand">rand</a>
    <hr>
'''


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return nav

@app.route('/rand', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def rand():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # return 'POST'
        return nav + generate_code()
    else:
        # return 'GET'
        return nav  + '''
            <form action="/rand" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            '''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: "у вас в вопросе стоит метка django, рискну предположить, что вам не принципиально" - очень рискованное предположение. Если метка стоит, то скорее всего она стоит не просто так.

Comment: а вот и правда вскрылась: © ...  с помощью ajax ,обращались к серверу и получали рандомное число просто я только начал изучать django ... . может пригодится кому. думаю для простого дёрганья скрипта, django избыточен

Comment: @qwabra просто хочу эту генерацию в дальнейшем использовать для других целей.
чтобы это рандомное число отправлялось на почту , как код проверки. 
ну возможно это слишком сложно для новичка и я рано в это полез

Comment: @user355827, (9 мегабайт)[https://pypi.org/project/Django/#files] против (625.5 килобайт)[https://pypi.org/project/Flask/#files] ;; (5 глав руководства)[https://metanit.com/python/django/] против приведённого мной примера. я не настаиваю ... : ) пробуйте, пишите. не забывайте указать какая операционка, если винда - это важно

Comment: @qwabra ну просто не думаю что стоит прыгать с одного фреемворка на другой)
особенно при начале изучения, раз выбрал django надо дальше мучатся)
спасибо за помощь, буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Никак, html и python работают на разных полюсах веба. Можно, конечно, сделать клиент-серверный запрос, но тогда надо использовать JavaScript, а в таком случае, не используя запросы, лучше сразу воспользоваться js-функцией `Math.random()` на стороне клиента.

Чтобы сгенерировать целое число из заданного диапазона можно использовать вот такую функцию (пример взят [отсюда](https://javascript.ru/Math.Random)):

```
// использование Math.round() даст неравномерное распределение, поэтому Math.floor()
function getRandomInt(min, max)
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: я имел ввиду django
где-то тут на форуме видел похожую тему, но потерял и не могу найти.
там вроде с помощью ajax ,обращались к серверу и получали рандомное число