# Какой выбрать язык для backend в связке с js, vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите друзья, занимаюсь изучением js. Появилась необходимость получать с сервера(mssql) данные в виде json. Думал примерно наваять какой-то апи, которому я буду передавать sql command, а он с сервера мне эти данные будет возвращать, но как правильнее и проще не знаю.

Comment: ? https://ru.nuxtjs.org/ ?? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1072389/232932

Comment: на чем удобно на том и делайте бэкенд (php/nodejs/Go/python/Java  и т.д), все равно вам однозначного ответа никто не даст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень обширный вопрос, который является одной из тем горячих споров в интернете)

Я часто использую php, просто потому что удобно и привычно. 
Можно использовать так же nodeJS.

Это 2 наиболее популярных варианта. Все зависит от ваших навыков/знаний/предпочтений, специфики и объема передаваемых данных и возможностей сервера, на котором этот бэкэнд будет крутиться.

Правильнее на стороне клиента реализовать запрос конкретных данных, а вот релевантная этому запросу sql команда должна быть на сервере.

Иначе образуется дыра в безопасности - через консоль пользователь сможет ввести requst со своей командой и беспрепятственно получит данные с сервера.